# Strange Bug with horizontal ListView inside Vertical SliverList

Tags: dart, flutter

After scrolling vertically upwards, the horizontal ListView scrolls itself to the right.

The error only occurs when, at the time the horizontal Listview is displayed, the finger no longer touches the touchscreen and the vertical SliverList continues to run by itself.

Here is the code to reproduce the error:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return CustomScrollView(
  slivers: <Widget>[
    SliverList(
      delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
        (context, index) {
          if (index == 0)
            return SizedBox(
              height: 50,
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemBuilder: (context, index) => Container(
                      width: 200,
                      color: Colors.black45,
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8),
                    ),
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              ),
            );
          return Container(
            height: 200,
            margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8),
            color: Colors.black45,
          );
        },
      ),
    )
  ],
);
}
```

[image: Scroll bug]

Comment: Can you show us how did you implement it ?

Comment: Of course! I edited the Question and added some more details. Thank you!

Comment: this code still doesn't reproduce your problem.. you might want to include how you set up the SliverAppBar...

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I'm facing the same problem.

Comment: I'm not quite shure anymore but I think it was because i have wrapped each page in to a PageStorageBucket

Answer (score 0):

You should add the key to your ListView.
In here, we can use `key: PageStorageKey()`